# How to print data in python console from flask webpage

Tags: html, python-3.x, flask, ninja

The code I am using is:

**My HTML code:**

```
<html>
   <body>

      <form action = "http://localhost:5000/login" method = "post">
         <p>Enter Name:</p>
         <p><input type = "text" name = "nm" /></p>
         <p><input type = "submit" value = "submit" /></p>
      </form>

   </body>
</html>
```

**My python code:**

```
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/success/<name>')

def success(name):

    return 'welcome %s' % name

@app.route('/login',methods = ['POST', 'GET'])

 def login():

    if request.method == 'POST':

        user = request.form['nm']    

        return redirect(url_for('success',name = user))

    else:

        user = request.args.get('nm')

        return redirect(url_for('success',name = user))

if __name__ == '__main__':

       app.run(debug = True)
```

How can I print data in python console from flask webpage?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please be a bit more specific when asking a question: *What do you expect?* / *What error do you get?* **For Help take a look at "[How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)"**

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys
print('Hello world!', file=sys.stderr)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and/or *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score -1):

use `print()` for whatever u want to print in the console.

Comment: sorry it couldn't work .I tried as                                                            user = request.args.get('nm')                                                      print(user)                                                                                           but it doesn't  print the name on python console

Comment: Can you update your question with what you want to print and what u tried

Comment: I want to print the value of 'user' in the python console

Comment: `print("Value of nm is %s" % nm)` or  `print("Value of nm is : "+nm)` both will print on Python console